# Meaning of Closed Relative

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm currently reading through Rudin's PMA, and I'm stuck on one of the haphazard statements that he makes after Definition 2.32:

> We observed earlier (in Sec. 2.29) that if $E \subset Y \subset X$, then $E$ may be open
> relative to $Y$ without being open relative to $X$. The property of being open thus
> depends on the space in which $E$ is embedded. The same is true of the property
> of being closed.

What I'm having trouble with is having a built definition to be closed relative to. Is it perhaps:

Suppose $Y \subset X$. Then some $E \subset Y$ is **closed relative** to $Y$ iff $E = Y \cap G$ for a closed subset $G$ of $X$? This is Rudin's definition of open relative but $G$ is changed to be a closed rather than open subset of $X$.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid definition of something being relatively closed. There might be an equivalent characterization that Rudin had in mind, but the definition that you've stumbled on is perfectly good.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Do you think it would be worthwhile that I characterize it using a limit point definition of closed sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space, and $Y\subset X$. Consider the function $d'$ given by restricting the domain of the metric $d:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ to $Y\times Y$. Then, $(Y,d')$ is a metric space in its own right, and for all $a,b\in Y$, we have $d(a,b)=d'(a,b)$.

If $E\subset Y$, then saying that "$E$ is open [closed] relative to $Y$" is just an abbreviation of saying that $E$ is open [closed] in the metric space $(Y,d')$. This was the definition that Rudin had in mind. However, one can prove that $E$ is open [closed] relative to $Y$ if and only if there is an open [closed] set $G$ (in the metric space $(X,d)$) such that $E=Y\cap G$.

(This definition also makes sense given the broader context of topological spaces: it ought to be the case that $E$ is open [closed] relative to $Y$ if and only if $E$ is open [closed] in $Y$ with the subspace topology. And indeed, this is true.)

Comment: Many thanks! Do you have resources that contain visuals for these topological concepts? I'm reading through Rudin as a form of self-study, and I've found myself almost lost with Chapter 2. I am slowly understanding the definitions, but I find it difficult to stick it into my head.

Comment: @blanket: Rudin is a very good reference book; it is also a good book for advanced undergraduate students, particularly those who are already somewhat familiar with the material covered. However, it is not a good book for self-study – it's just too terse. Assuming you have taken a course in real analysis before, I would recommend Terence Tao's *Analysis II*, which is beautifully written and its first chapter is on metric spaces. If you need to review a bit of analysis, try *Analysis I* by Tao.

Comment: @blanket: Tao only briefly covers the more general topic of topological spaces, but that's okay – the most important topological spaces in analysis are also metric spaces. I don't think Tao provides many visuals, but he does give plenty of examples. And you can draw pictures yourself in the case of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$, say. This should you in building your intuition.